# update sql column with php while loop

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am trying to update my table column but I keep getting one value for all the rows, what am I doing wrong?

```html
<?php

$count = 1;
while ( $count <= 30) {
    $fmle_img = "_src/img/profile/female/u$count.png";
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET image=:image WHERE (id > 31 AND id < 62)", array(':image'=>$fmle_img));
    $count ++;
}

// this keeps giving me _src/img/profile/female/30.png for all the rows between id 32 and id 61

?>
```

Comment: Your criteria never changes. So it updates the records 30 times. 30 is just the last time.

Comment: how do I change it? I'm stuck

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must vary the where condition for each image:

```
<?php

$count = 1;

while ( $count <= 30) {

    $id = $count + 32;
    $fmle_img = "_src/img/profile/female/u$count.png";
    
    $db->query('UPDATE users SET image = :image WHERE id = :id', array(':image'=>$fmle_img, ':id' => $id));
    
    $count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a single id in the WHERE clause of your sql statement.
Try `WHERE id = :id` and pass as `:id` `$count+30`.